# Cannot assign a string containing '>' to a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am assigning a string to a javascript variable. But it generates error.

Method1

```js
jquery = "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js'></script>";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
          <title>old</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
    hai
    </body>
</html>
```

Method2

```js
jquery = "<script src=";
                    jquery1 = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js";
                    jquery2 = "></script>";
                    console.log(jquery + jquery1 + jquery2);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
          <title>old</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
    hai
    </body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT

hai ";

why '";' is added after the string "hai".

How should I solve this? Please help me understand..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? What error do you get ?

Comment: What's the error? You've also not declared your variable, unless this is done elsewhere: `var jqury = ...`?

Comment: See the html output..you will get to know..

Comment: You are missing the plus. `jqury+=""`

Comment: tried with jqury+="" but no use.